# How to Change existing Imagelist image size of Listview

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the imagelist image size while listview is active and contains items. But it seems it only affect the new added images, the existing image will became blank.

Here is my codes:

```
public Form1()
{
    ...
    imglst_ = new ImageList();
    imglst_.ImageSize = new Size(80, 80);
    listView1.SmallImageList = imglst_;
    listView1.LargeImageList = imglst_;
    ...
}

//zoom in
//This code only affect the new added image
//the existing images will become blank
private void toolStripZoomin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int w = imglst_.ImageSize.Width;
    int h = imglst_.ImageSize.Height;

    w = (int)(w * 1.2);
    h = (int)(h * 1.2);

    imglst_.ImageSize = new Size(w, h);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [`ImageSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagesize(v=vs.110).aspx) property states:

> Setting the `ImageSize` property prior to adding images to the image collection causes the images to be resized to the image size specified.
>
> When you set the `ImageSize` property to a new value, the `Handle` for the
>   image list is recreated.
>
> Because setting the `ImageSize` property causes the handle to be
>   recreated, **you should set ImageSize prior to setting the Images
>   property.** When the handle for the `ImageList` has been created, setting
>   the `ColorDepth` or `ImageSize` properties in code, after setting the
>   Images property, will cause the collection of images set for the
>   Images property to be deleted.

So you can't change the `ImageSize` after adding the images, you should add the images again to the `ImageList` after setting the `ImageSize` so they will be drawn in the newly specified size.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the size of an already initialized imagelist, using ImageSize, unfortunately all handles are destroyed, and previous images are not available anymore. But, if you save your images in a temporary collection, you can reset the existing ImageList and inject again all previous icons with the proper key. My code is the following:

```
public static void ResizeImageList(ImageList imageList, int newSize)
{
    var OldImages = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
    foreach (string imgKey in imageList.Images.Keys)
    {
        OldImages.Add(imgKey, imageList.Images[imgKey]);
    }
    imageList.ImageSize = new Size(newSize, newSize);
    imageList.Images.Clear();
    foreach (string imgKey in OldImages.Keys)
    {
        imageList.Images.Add(imgKey, OldImages[imgKey]);
    }
}
```