# Dynamically change listview icon size in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I'm trying to make a listview with options. One of the option is to change icon size. I tried to make the change like this :

```
this.listview1.LargeImageList.ImageSize = this.list.SmallImageList.ImageSize = new Size(h, w);
```

This changed the image size, but the image disappeared. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following link, I think it should be useful:

[How to Change existing Imagelist image size of Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301283/how-to-change-existing-imagelist-image-size-of-listview)

use the following code. it works for me :

```
listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
ImageList iList = new ImageList();
iList.ImageSize = new Size(128, 128);
iList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
iList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.x64_Clear_icon); 
listView1.LargeImageList = iList;
```

Comment: I tried to recreate LargeImageList and SmallImageList, but the images are changing(final images are grey). The way that I'm doing that is:

Comment: ImageList tmp = new ImageList();
            tmp.ImageSize = new Size(h, w);
            foreach(Image img in this.list.LargeImageList.Images) { tmp.Images.Add(img); }
            this.list.LargeImageList = this.list.SmallImageList = tmp;

Comment: use the following code. it works for me :
            listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
            ImageList iList = new ImageList();
            iList.ImageSize = new Size(128, 128);
            iList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
            iList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.x64_Clear_icon); 
            listView1.LargeImageList = iList;